# How to get the details of another file info using getter & setter methods in c#?

Tags: c#

```
static string sm_strVersion;
a = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
sm_strVersion = "Version:" + a.GetName().Version;
//version.cs file contains below code:

namespace FInclude
{
    public partial class CFontData
    {
        public readonly string ToolVersion = "FL.001";
    }
}
```

Can someone please explain about `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()`?

Where I can get documentation on all the built-in functions in c#?

Comment: You can read about GetEntryAssembly [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getentryassembly.aspx). What exactly is it that you are having issues with?

Comment: Are you just after the ability to read the version numbers and copyright etc of selected file?

Comment: Nine Questions, no answer accepted. Do you need help with how stackoverflow works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find an explanation of what `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` does [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getentryassembly.aspx).

What do you mean by where you can get all the features? You mean documentation? Then start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/).

Answer (score 1):

`Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` returns an object of type `Assembly`. All available methods and properties can be found in the [`System.Reflection.Assembly` class documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

As Dennis state that `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() returns an object of type Assembly`, and this Assembly contains the `'Main'` method (which is the entrypoint).